# How should I correct my program in matlab?(sorting application)

Tags: matlab

```
max=0;
min=0;
for i=1:10
array(i)=input("Enter your numbers: ");
fprintf("Numbers are array(%d)=%d ",i,array(i));
end
for i=1:10
if(i==10)
 break;
else
if(array(i)>array(i+i))
max=array(i);
elseif(array(i)<array(i+1))
min=array(i);
end
end
end
```

My program's aim is to find the maximum and minimum number in 10 numbers.
ERROR:Index exceeds the number of array elements (10).

Error in Untitled5 (line 11)
if(array(i)>array(i+1))

How can I prevent my error?Thanks.

Comment: First, you need to properly indent your code. It will help you to read and debug your code more effectively. Second, you need to read the error message and find where the error condition holds. In this case, the index exceeds 10. In the line mentioned, your indices are `i` and `i+1`. Since `i+1` is greater than `i`, you can assume that this is your problem. When is `i+10 > 10`?

Comment: As a side note, you should avoid using magic numbers like `10` in your code. Instead, set a variable to the value `10` at the beginning and use that variable throughout. This way you only have to change the value in one place if you decide to change the array size. Overshadowing the built-in [imaginary unit `i`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/i.html) should also be avoided when possible.

Comment: When you fix that bug, and also this one: `array(i+i)`, you’ll notice that your program doesn’t find the largest value in the array, instead it returns the last value that is larger than its next value. Instead, set `max` to the first value, then compare each value in turn with `max`, and, if it’s larger, update max.

Comment: Thanks Cris Luengo, I got it then the problem is solved but I don't understand that when i is equal to 10, It's necessary to exit my program by  "break" command. Thus, my program will be working properly but  my program may be non-functional according to your comments. I wanted to prevent passing to 11th index. Could you observe the reason of being non-function according to above code? (I want to say again that the program is corrected)